# SLURM read from disks of other nodes

Tags: slurm

I have a situation that using the terminal (on the PC main-node) I can entry in a disk belongs to another PC (on the PC node1), but with SLURM no.

On the terminal: I'm in the main node "/mnt/main-node" and I cd to go in a node "/mnt/node1". With this everything is working.

If I run the above as script, running it from the "/mnt/main-node":

```
srun entry.sh
```

The script is:

```
pwd
cd /mnt/node1
pwd
```

Slurm can not entry/find the directory ...

```
/mnt/main-node
entry.sh: line 2: cd: /mnt/node1: No such file or directory
/mnt/main-node
```

on the main-node PC I see this

```
drwxrwxrwx  7 nobody nogroup  12K Jun  5 12:48 node1/
```

and on the node1 PC I have this

```
drwxrwxrwx  7 nobody nogroup  12K Jun  5 12:48 node1/
```

I'm using NFS to connect the disks.

*New extra info 17/08/23*
Running the "entry.sh" script with the salloc - interactive job, I can entry. With srun and sbatch I can not.

why slurm can not entry in the disk of the node1 PC and how can I fix it? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try salloc

Slurm will open interactive console in the node. If you are not able to see disk from there (directly  connected to the node but throug the slurm queue),you can't either launch jobs as your script.

If I understand your problem you are exporting nfs and the node is not able to map it.

I guess /etc/exports in master and the service is enabled.
/etc/fstab in client (in addition to nsf client software)  is  right also?
Check users and ids too. Maybe it is useful to have the same users and ids in master and nodes. You have to take care of this when deployments  of images are enabled but  it can  be manually done just copying users and groups files.

Hope it helps.

Comment: for NFS /etc/exports I use these options: (rw,sync,no_subtree_check)

Comment: The node1 disk is mounted with NFS on the main node, I can see it running "df -h". When I activate an interactive job with salloc, I can entry, both manualy with "cd" and running the "entry.sh" script directly on the terminal - but still not with srun or sbatch. The disk mount is not in the fstab because I do not want it permantely mounted - after every re-start of the nodes I manually mount the "extra" HDD/SSD of the system. UID and GID are the same numbers and names in all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am not understanging your issue but  what do you mean with slurm?
Slurm i s queue so the jobs will be allocated in the nodes. This is the place where you must have access to the resources.
The same command working in salloc could be implemented in sbatch file.
An example could  be

```
vi script.sh

#!/bin/bash
cd /mnt/node1
```

---

Finally in your login or master node

```
sbatch script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your time!

In general slurm is working well with all nodes, running jobs: interactive (salloc)/sbatch/srun. The problem is to access the sbatch and srun jobs in the disks located outside of the master node / controller - I can submit jobs only from the controller.

If I take your script and I'm running it opening first an interactive job (salloc) then it is working.

If I go to run your script as "sbatch script.sh" or "srun script.sh" it doesn't work, can not find the directory. "node1" folder is part of a disk located in the cluster node "1" and it is connected with the controller (named "node" here) with NFS.

If in your scrip I add at the start "sleep 60" I see the job running, both as sbatch and srun ... but when it go to the next command "cd" is going to dye because it can not find the directory (the directory in any case is correct because if I copy and paste it I can manually entry in the folder, moving from the "node" to the "node1").

I suppose that using "drwxrwxrwx  7 nobody nogroup" there should not be any restriction for SLURM, as also all accounts are registred in the slurm system. Do I need to add the "*nobody*" account in the slurm system or is there any other suggestion?